# Marklogic : Insert and retrieve document using xquery in the same run

Tags: xquery, marklogic

Need something like this in `Marklogic` by using `xquery`.
Get a document present in a location, if not present create a document using `xdmp:document-insert()` and then retrieve document using `fn:doc()`.

In the first run, document is not present. So it creates the document but does not fetch anything. In the second run, document created in the first run is retrieved. But, I want to do both in the same run.

I know that I am missing something simple here. Is it the case with single transaction? Both the statements are in separate lines, so not sure wether it is a single transaction case.

```
    declare function lk:createXmlIfNotPresent(){
       let $xml_dir := "app/test"
       let $xml_full_path := "app/test/test.xml"
       let $dir_uri := cts:uri-match($xml_dir)
       let $dir_creation :=
       if(fn:empty($xml_dir)) then (
            xdmp:directory-create($xml_dir)
        )else()
       let $exists := fn:doc-available($xml_full_path)
       let $xml_creation :=
       if($exists eq fn:false()) then (
        xdmp:document-insert($xml_full_path,<root></root>,xdmp:default-  permissions())
       )else()
       return fn:doc($xml_full_path)
  };
```

Comment: You can circumvent the transaction fuss here by simply returning <root></root> if it doesn't already exist instead of using fn:doc..

Comment: I want the document to be written in to ML @grtjn. I would be using this xml in other functions in the same xquery

Comment: You can still do that, as long as you pass the result of this function around, instead of using fn:doc everywhere..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this has to do with transactions. The entire body of an `XQuery` program, by default, it's running in a single transaction. Unlike `RDBMS` transactions, in ML a transaction *hides* what it does. Your view of the database remains unchanged through the life of the transaction. Only when the program is complete, the changes are committed and visible.

You can work around/with this in various ways, I suggest this tutorial.

https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/transactions

Answer (score 1):

While the advice about transactions is true for the general case, this case can be handled simply.

You already have the document in memory (<root/> in the example) as the second parameter to `xdmp:document-insert()`.

You can assign the document to a variable. Pass the document to `xdmp:document-insert()`, and also return the document.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do both in the same run use xdmp:eval() function to create your document.